# Sort the lists in a dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a program which produces the following:

```
{'Jim': [4, 2, 6], 'Fred': [5, 3, 8], 'Neil': [5, 1, 7]}
```

I would like to be able to sort the numbers in [] from highest to lowest.

e.g.

```
{'Jim': [6, 4, 2], 'Fred': [8, 5, 3], 'Neil': [7, 5, 1]}
```

I would then like to be able to display their name followed by their highest score, please could you tell me how to do this. I am coding in Python

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sorted` function to do sorting. `reverse=True` should sort the data in reverse order ie, from highest to lowest.

```
>>> d = {'Jim': [4, 2, 6], 'Fred': [5, 3, 8], 'Neil': [5, 1, 7]}
>>> {i:sorted(j, reverse=True) for i,j in d.items()}
{'Jim': [6, 4, 2], 'Neil': [7, 5, 1], 'Fred': [8, 5, 3]}
>>> {i:max(j) for i,j in d.items()}
{'Jim': 6, 'Neil': 7, 'Fred': 8}
```

Comment: temp variables which refer the keys and values. `dict.items()` should return a list of tuples where the first elem represents key and the second represents value.

Comment: Thanks, can I now get it to just display the first value with the name?

Comment: Thanks, is their an easy way to get the names in alphabetical order?

Comment: you need to use orderedict.

Comment: Thanks again, final question is their a way instead of doing max to do average? Really appreciate your help

Comment: get the 0th index in sorted, `sorted(j, reverse=True)[0]`

Comment: Where abouts in the above code should it go? Could you give me an example. Thanks

Comment: `{i:sorted(j, reverse=True)[0] for i,j in d.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary comprehension and `sorted`.

```
>>> d = {'Jim': [4, 2, 6], 'Fred': [5, 3, 8], 'Neil': [5, 1, 7]}
>>> {k:sorted(d[k], reverse=True) for k in d}
{'Jim': [6, 4, 2], 'Neil': [7, 5, 1], 'Fred': [8, 5, 3]}
```

This will give you a new dictionary where the values (i.e. the lists) are sorted in descending order. If you want to sort the lists in place, use

```
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...     d[k] = sorted(v, reverse=True)
... 
>>> d
{'Jim': [6, 4, 2], 'Neil': [7, 5, 1], 'Fred': [8, 5, 3]}
```

If you are using Python3, change `d.iteritems()` to `d.items()`.

> I would then like to be able to display their name followed by their highest score, please could you tell me how to do this. I am coding in Python

Two options. If we assume `d_sorted` is your dictionary with the sorted lists, iterate over it and print the name and the first element of each list.

```
>>> for name, scores in d_sorted.iteritems():
...     print name, scores[0]
... 
'Jim', 6
'Neil', 7
'Fred', 8
```

But if that's all you want to do, a simpler way would be to use `max` and not pre-sort the lists at all. Assume that `d` is your original dictionary:

```
>>> for name, scores in d.iteritems():
...     print name, max(scores)
... 
'Jim', 6
'Neil', 7
'Fred', 8
```

Comment: Thanks, can you stop it displaying the '' ?

Comment: @zoomingcats no problem. The comment section is not really a good place to discuss follow up questions to your original question because the code formatting options are very limited. If you have a specific follow up question (which cannot already be found on stackoverflow) go ahead and open a new question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Lists can be sorted inplace so unless you need a new dict you don't need to create one just call `list.sort` on each value/list:

```
d = {'Jim': [4, 2, 6], 'Fred': [5, 3, 8], 'Neil': [5, 1, 7]}
for sub in d.values():
  sub.sort(reverse=1)
print(d)
{'Neil': [7, 5, 1], 'Jim': [6, 4, 2], 'Fred': [8, 5, 3]}
```